# Can't remove node module file in mac

Tags: macos

When i try run this command

`rm -rf node_modules`

I get this error:

```
rm: node_modules/core-js/core/function.js: Illegal byte sequence
```

how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like theres some encoding issues with this file. You can do:

```
LC_ALL=C rm -rf node_modules
```

Or you can try setting these two vars before you run your rm command.

```
export LC_CTYPE=C 
export LANG=C
```

You can also add this in your `.bashrc` file but it will cause issues in other places.